# Updating XML File (C#/Linq)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, linq

I'm trying to figure out how I can go about updating my XML file. I know how to read and write, but no idea how to update an existing record.

My XML file looks like:

And I'd like to be able to change the value of an XAttribute that's already in the file.

This is how I'm writing the file:

```
        XElement xElement;
        xElement = new XElement("Orders");

        XElement element = new XElement(
            "Order",
            new XAttribute("Quantity", Quantity),
            new XAttribute("Part No", PartNo),
            new XAttribute("Description", Description),
            new XAttribute("Discount", Discount),
            new XAttribute("Freight", Freight),
            new XAttribute("Unit Value", UnitValue),
            new XAttribute("Line Total", LineTotal)
            );
        xElement.Add(element);
        xElement.Save("");
```

Is it possible to do updates, or must we first remove the existing one, and then re-add it with the new values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can update the attribute without deleting and re-adding. Simply get the desired `XAttribute` object inside the XElement and update it's `Value` property and save back the XElement to a file to see the changes.

```
xElement.Attribute("Quantity").Value = "15";
```

Comment: hmmm.. Thanks - that makes sense :) Me and my old buddy IntelliSense will figure the rest out :P